# Getting the last version number before a particular version number in CVS

Tags: cvs

I have a project that uses CVS and recently bumped the baseline to the next major revision, 4.0. What I am trying to do, is get the last version of a file before that bump (programatically, I know I can inspect the file in an editor).

For instance, if I have the following couple files with versions, I want to get what is after the arrow (=>):

```
 makefile ... 3.4, 3.5, 4.0       => 3.5
 main.cc  ... 3.9. 3.10, 4.0, 4.1 => 3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
cvs rlog -b YourModuleName 2>/dev/null |sed '$bd;/^RCS file:/{:d;x;s/\n/\t/g;s/revision[.0-9\t ]*revision //;s/\trevision.*$//;n};/^revision/H;d'
```

For a file that has only one revision it will print its name but no revision.